#  Pull to Refresh crashes app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to Objective-c so i am kinda stumped, I have it on another part of my app, and works flawlessly, but when i use it on a different view of my app, it crashes the app, and Im pretty sure i have it set up the same way.

I got Xcode to put a breakpoint at the code that messes up and its teh top line of this code

```
    NSArray *timesArray = [self.tableDataArray objectAtIndex:2];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [timesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"time"];
    cell.destinationLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"destination"];
```

the NSArray *timesArray is what is stops at, but no other errors or anything is given so I am kinda stumped to what to change.

EDIT NUMBER 1:
Deleted old edit for sake of clarity.

EDIT NUMBER 2

ok so i checked again slowly, and what happens is it does 3 full parses of the data, and outputs all the stuff i have.

```
2012-06-21 13:37:09.148 NextBus[5990:1a603] Array: (
    {
    routeName = "Oxford West";
    routeNumber = 17;
    stopDirection = Westbound;
    stopName = "Griffith At Commissioners Sb";
    stopNumber = 811;
},
"Next 3 Vehicles Arrive At:",
    (
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "1:58 P.M.";
    },
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "2:15 P.M.";
    },
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "2:35 P.M.";
    }
),
"Prediction Last Updated 1:37:06 Pm 6/21/2012"
)
2012-06-21 13:37:09.148 NextBus[5990:1a603] Array: (
    {
    routeName = "Oxford West";
    routeNumber = 17;
    stopDirection = Westbound;
    stopName = "Griffith At Commissioners Sb";
    stopNumber = 811;
},
"Next 3 Vehicles Arrive At:",
    (
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "1:58 P.M.";
    },
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "2:15 P.M.";
    },
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "2:35 P.M.";
    }
),
"Prediction Last Updated 1:37:06 Pm 6/21/2012"
)
2012-06-21 13:37:09.149 NextBus[5990:1a603] Array: (
    {
    routeName = "Oxford West";
    routeNumber = 17;
    stopDirection = Westbound;
    stopName = "Griffith At Commissioners Sb";
    stopNumber = 811;
},
"Next 3 Vehicles Arrive At:",
    (
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "1:58 P.M.";
    },
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "2:15 P.M.";
    },
            {
        destination = "To Byron Baseline / Griffith";
        time = "2:35 P.M.";
    }
),
"Prediction Last Updated 1:37:06 Pm 6/21/2012"
)
```

its WHEN i pull to refresh it does

```
2012-06-21 13:37:45.590 NextBus[5990:1a603] Array: (
    {
    routeName = "Oxford West";
    routeNumber = 17;
    stopDirection = Westbound;
    stopName = "Griffith At Commissioners Sb";
    stopNumber = 811;
}
)
```

and then crashes, it stops parsing, for some reason.

It is the EGO pull to refresh kit.

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.tableDataArray);` before the bad line.  What does it display?

Comment: Obvious, I suppose, but something must be changing the contents of `self.tableDataArray` between calls.  (The posted code is from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I assume.)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

It seems that the crash occurs when your query returns insufficient data, e.g., when no times are available for next buses. If you can confirm this, then the fix is trivial:

```
if ([self.tableDataArray count] > 1) {
  NSArray *timesArray = [self.tableDataArray objectAtIndex:2];
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [timesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.timeLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"time"];
  cell.destinationLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"destination"];
} else {
  //-- do something to show that no times are available
}
```

You are likely trying to access an array beyond its bounds:

```
    NSArray *timesArray = [self.tableDataArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

`timesArray` has not got 3 elements, then the program crashes...

You should review the way the array is populated vs. your expectations from this operation.

EDIT:

based on the edit you did to your question, it seems that you are executing the lines you posted a few times and only the last time the program crashes. As you can see, on the first couple of iterations, your array is populated with enough elements; in the last case:

```
2012-06-21 13:25:03.448 NextBus[5964:1a603] Array: (
{
routeName = Springbank;
routeNumber = 5;
stopDirection = Eastbound;
stopName = "Berkshire At Berkshire Place Sb";
stopNumber = 2196;
}
```

the array has only got one object. Is this a corner case you should handle differently?

Comment: Looking at this, I shouldnt need all that information, I am populating a view, that just shows the times of the next 3 buses, which it does, I dont know what i did to make it loop that many times. 

I only need one instance of the times.